# Left weighted fast search on large text dataset - Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

I have a large dataset that I would like to use for autocomplete (>1M records) on mysql.

As an example I am typing "Methanol" and wanting typeahead suggestions..

Currently I have

```
select AgentReferenceName as name
from tblAgentReference 
where AgentReferenceName like '%methan%' 
order by instr(AgentReferenceName,'methan'), char_length(AgentReferenceName) 
limit 10;
```

This does the job nicely, but is a bit slow

```
+-------------+
| name        |
+-------------+
| Methan      |
| Methane     |
| Methane     |
| Methane     |
| Methanal    |
| Methanol    |
| Methanol    |
| Methanide   |
| Methanamine |
| Methanamine |
+-------------+
10 rows in set (3.52 sec)
```

I have a fulltext index on the field but when I run the usual fulltext weighted search - it bumps up the larger words so I get

```
select AgentReferenceName as name  from tblAgentReference  where match(AgentReferenceName) against ('methano*' in boolean mode)   order by match(AgentReferenceName) against ('methano*') limit 10;     
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| name                                                                                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2,4-Methanoacridin-9-amine, 8-fluoro-1,2,3,4-tetrahydro-, 2-hydroxy-1,2,3-propanetricarboxylate (3:2)    |
| 9-Amino-8-fluoro-1,2,3,4-tetrahydro-2,4-methanoacridine                                                  |
| 9-Amino-8-fluoro-1,2,3,4-tetrahydro-2,4-methanoacridine                                                  |
| 2,4-Methanoadamantane                                                                                    |
| 2,4-Methanoadamantane                                                                                    |
| 2-Amino-4,5-methanoadipate                                                                               |
| 1,4-Methanoanthra(2,3-c)oxepin-7,12-dione, 1,3,4,5-tetrahydro-4,6,13-trihydroxy-3,11-dimethoxy-3-methyl- |
| 1,4-Methanoanthracene-9,10-dione, 1,2,3,4-tetrahydro-                                                    |
| 1,4-Methanoanthracene-9,10-dione, 1,2,3,4-tetrahydro-                                                    |
| 1,4-Methanoanthracene-9,10-dione, 1,2,3,4,4a,9a-hexahydro-                                               |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.13 sec)
```

So speed is good, but results are terrible

My question - how to do a fast search that returns similar to the like query, but nearer to the speed of the fulltext one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Some random thoughts...)

```
WHERE MATCH(...) AGAINST(...)
  AND ... LIKE ...
```

It *should* filter using `FULLTEXT` first, then further filter via `LIKE`.

But... I am puzzled by your current code.  The first example (using `instr`) *tends* to pick data *starting with* "Methan".  That can be much more efficiently performed with

```
AgentReferenceName LIKE 'Methan%'
```

assuming you have `INDEX(AgentReferenceName).  If`AgentReferenceName`is`TEXT`and not`VARCHAR`, then consider an extra column with just short names indexed.

Then consider

```
( SELECT ... WHERE ... LIKE 'Methan%' ... LIMIT 10 )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT ... WHERE MATCH ... LIMIT 10 )
```

This will give you up to 20 rows for further sorting (and whittling down to 10) -- possibly in app code.

Comment: trying select AgentReferenceName as name  from tblAgentReference  where match(AgentReferenceName) against ('methano*' in boolean mode) AND AgentReferenceName LIKE 'methano%' order by instr(AgentReferenceName,'methan') limit 10; gave me a much faster search of 1.17 sec - I think I will go with this for the moment.. I will try teh additional column later

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with this exact problem. Here's what I did.

When the user furnished autocomplete string is one or two characters long, ignore it. Don't attempt to autocomplete (unless you have a record of the user's own previous searches).

When the user furnished autocomplete string is relatively short (try six characters) use   `WHERE name LIKE CONCAT(:userstring, '%')` and thereby search for strings *beginning* with what the user wants. That can exploit the index. The user may find the string she wants and choose it, and you're done.

When the user furnished string is longer, use a different query with `WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', :userstring, '%')`. Only for a longer string offer the performance killing search with the leading `%`. Performance will still stink, but the feature will get used less often.

Your best bet is, like Rick James mentioned, creating a table containing strings that *start* with the search terms you most often expect. Then you can always use `LIKE 'searchterm%'` and avoid the leading `%` altogether.

FULLTEXT has, as you've discovered, some limitations when you use it for autocomplete.

Comment: I like this one in combination with the first answer.. will do it on the php side I think instead though..